# “greatest-n-per-group” query in Django 2.0?

Tags: django, greatest-n-per-group

Basically, I want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group?noredirect=1&lq=1) but with django 2.0.

If I try:

`Purchases.objects.filter(.....).annotate(my_max=Window(
    expression=Max('field_of_interest'),
    partition_by=F('customer')
    )
)`

I get back all the rows but with the `my_max` property added to each record.

Comment: What if you have multiple rows with greatest value in some groups? What should be the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL:

```
Purchases.objects.filter(.....).order_by(
    'customer', '-field_of_interest'
).distinct('customer')
```

**UPDATE: Window expressions are not allowed in filter, so following methods does not work. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489786/6627564) for up-to-date solution**

or with `Window` expression

```
Purchases.objects.filter(.....).annotate(my_max=Window(
    expression=Max('field_of_interest'),
    partition_by=F('customer')
    )
).filter(my_max=F('field_of_interest'))
```

but latter can yield multiple rows per customer if they have the same `field_of_interest`

Another `Window`, with single row per customer

```
Purchases.objects.filter(.....).annotate(row_number=Window(
        expression=RowNumber(),
        partition_by=F('customer'),
        order_by=F('field_of_interest').desc()
        )
    ).filter(row_number=1)
```

Comment: one followup: when I try the last query I get an error: `django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.`  Each row has the correct `row_number` property but right now I am using python not the db to get rid of all records with a row_number > 1. Any way around this?

Comment: Oh,  that's unexpected to me. I think if it is unsupported   then unfortunately it is unsupported..