# Django selecting top n records per group using ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140307/greatest-n-per-group-query-in-django-2-0), I'm trying to get top 10 records per each group_by critera, but Django return this error:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber

Purchases.objects.annotate(row_number=Window(
        expression=RowNumber(),
        partition_by=F('customer'),
        order_by=F('field_of_interest').desc()
        )
    ).filter(row_number=10)
```

```
raise NotSupportedError(
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.
```

When I remove .desc(), error message changes to:

```
ValueError: order_by must be either an Expression or a sequence of expressions.
```

I'm using PostgreSql. Is it a bug or am I wrong somewhere in my query?

Comment: Does this help? Django ticket #30104 [Need filtering by Window expression](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30104)

Comment: Thanks, @StevenRumbalski. Is there any other way to get top 10 records for each group_by value?

Comment: Can you look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924129/7320045? Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 12):

We can select top n per group with help of [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

Firstly, let's get top n Purchases per customer

```
top_n_purchases_per_customer = Purchases.objects.filter(
    customer=OuterRef('customer')
).order_by('-field_of_interest')[:10]
```

Next, we can select Purchases with matching ids from the top 10 per each customer.

```
top_n_purchases = Purchases.objects.filter(
    id__in=Subquery(top_n_purchases_per_customer.values('id'))
)
```

The generated query makes use of correlated subquery, so can become slow. Make sure to use index for `field_of_interest` and `customer` (preferably combined index by both fields (see [index_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#index-together) in Django docs))