# How to limit top N of each group in Django ORM by using Postgres Window functions or Lateral Joins?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, lateral-join, django-subquery

I have following `Post`, `Category` & `PostScore` Model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='category_posts', limit_choices_to={'parent_category': None}, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                        related_name='sub_categories', null=True, blank=True,
                                        limit_choices_to={'parent_category': None})
    ...
    ...

class PostScore(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_score')
    total_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, default=0)
    ...
    ...
```

So what i want is to write a query which returns `N` number of posts (**Posts**) of each distinct category  (**Category**) sorted by post score (denoted by total_score column in **PostScore** model) in descending manner. So that i have  atmost N records of each category with highest post score.

So i can achieve the above mentioned thing by the following raw query which gives me top 10 posts having highest score of each category :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "post"."category_id" 
           ORDER BY "postscore"."total_score" DESC) AS "rank"
    FROM
         "post"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         "postscore" 
    ON
       ("post"."id" = "postscore"."post_id") 
    WHERE 
       ("post"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "post"."status" = 'accepted') 
    ORDER BY 
        "postscore"."total_score" 
    DESC
) final_posts
WHERE 
    rank <= 10
```

What i have achieved so far using Django ORM:

```
>>> from django.db.models.expressions import Window
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Rank
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> posts = Post.objects.annotate(
                                 rank=Window( expression=Rank(), 
                                 order_by=F('post_score__total_score').desc(),
                                 partition_by[F('category_id')]
                                 )). \
            filter(status='accepted', deleted_at__isnull=True). \
            order_by('-post_score__total_score')
```

which roughly evaluates to

```
>>> print(posts.query)
>>> SELECT *,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "post"."category_id" 
       ORDER BY "postscore"."total_score" DESC) AS "rank"
     FROM
          "post"
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          "postscore" 
     ON
         ("post"."id" = "postscore"."post_id") 
     WHERE 
         ("post"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "post"."status" = 'accepted') 
     ORDER BY 
         "postscore"."total_score" 
     DESC
```

So basically what is missing that i need to limit each group (i.e category) results by using “rank” alias.

Would love to know how this can be done ?

I have seen one answer suggested by [Alexandr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6627564/alexandr-tatarinov) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60478733/django-selecting-top-n-records-per-group-using-orm), one way of achieving this is by using **Subquery** and **in** operator . Although it satisfies the above condition and outputs the right results but the *query is very slow.*

Anyway  this would be the query if I go by Alexandr suggestions:

```
>>> from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
>>> q = Post.objects.filter(status='accepted', deleted_at__isnull=True, 
    category=OuterRef('category')).order_by('-post_score__total_score')[:10]
>>> posts = Post.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(q.values('id')))
```

So i am more keen in completing the above raw query *(which is almost done just **misses** the **limit** part)* by using **window** function in ORM. Also, i think this can be achieved by using [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html) so answers in this direction are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

So I have got a workaround using **RawQuerySet** but the things is it returns a `django.db.models.query.RawQuerySet` which won't support methods like *filter, exclude* etc.

```
>>> posts = Post.objects.annotate(rank=Window(expression=Rank(), 
            order_by=F('post_score__total_score').desc(),
            partition_by=[F('category_id')])).filter(status='accepted', 
            deleted_at__isnull=True)
>>> sql, params = posts.query.sql_with_params()
>>> posts = Post.objects.raw(""" SELECT * FROM ({}) final_posts WHERE 
                                 rank <= %s""".format(sql),[*params, 10],)
```

I'll wait for the answers which provides a solution which returns a **QuerySet**  object instead, otherwise i have to do by this way only.